# Spring-Data Pageable sort on JPA discriminator field

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I've got a JPA entity hierarchy with JPA joined inheritance:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
Product
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_quiz")
@DiscriminatorValue("quiz")
public class QuizProduct extends Product
```

I want to run a spring-data query with QueryByExample and `PageRequest` like this:

```
Example<Product> example = ...
PageRequest pageRequest = ...
Page<Product> productPage = productRepository.findAll(example, pageRequest);
```

It works fine, except if I set `sortField` of the `pageRequest` to be "type" (the `@DiscriminatorColumn`).

I've tried to:

- directly add the type field to the entity. This way the query runs fine, but the persisting operation fails with `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 11, number of columns: 10`.
- if I mark this field as `@Transient`, the persisting works, but the query gives me this exception: `Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [type] on this ManagedType [...AbstractEntityWithDate]` (AbstractEntityWithDate is a `@MappedSuperclass` of `Product`, which contains `creationDate` and `modificationDate`)

I'm using spring-boot version 1.4.5.RELEASE with the dependency-managed versions of spring-data-jpa(1.10.8.RELEASE) and hibernate(5.0.12.Final).

How can I configure the sorting by discriminator field with `Pageable`? (I don't want to write custom `@Query` for this).

Comment: You cannot use a discriminator field in JPQL, so you cannot with Spring either. The only way to use columns with no class representation is to use native queries

Comment: Thanks! Although i not fully agree with this (there is type(t) in JPA and t.class as workaround in hibernate), your comment helped me to find this workaround:
https://theodoreyoung.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/jpa-and-hibernate-problems-with-polymorphic-queries/
Looks like it works for me, and if no better answer arrives for some time, i will post this as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Discriminator columns can be mapped as read-only entity attributes

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
class Product {
  @Column(name = "TYPE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private String type;
}
```

Then, the following query will work:

```
productRepository.findAll(new Sort("type"))
```

Working sample available [on Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/43974210).

---

Having said this, attempting to use the discriminator value in code with inheritance strategy `JOINED` will not work with Hibernate (`type` will always be `null`). This is because traditionally Hibernate has not supported `@DiscriminatorColumn` with `JOINED` (see [HHH-6911](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6911)) and has only started to save the column value for joined inheritance with v4.2.9 onwards. It seems like there is still a bug that does not read the discriminator column value, even though the value is saved correctly.

Comment: Thanks! Basically i found the same workaround (what i linked in OP comment), but this answer is extended with other useful infos and a working code example, so it absolutely deserves the correct answer mark :)

Comment: @C-Shark, my apologies for not paying attention to the comment earlier. I would not have posted the answer if I had viewed the linked content earlier. I initially wanted to post the bit about read-only attributes as a comment but also wanted to draw your attention to HHH-6911, which is something I have been burnt with a few times, which is why I had to post the details as an answer. Thanks for your generosity in accepting the answer.